# icecc - icecream seems to have invoked itself recursively

Tags: build-system

I have installed `icecream` on Fedora Linux and when I type in the console `icecc` I have an error like:

`ICECC[7893] 2020-06-01 14:09:55: icecream seems to have invoked itself recursively!`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I found that I have a recursive call on icecc. I'am using colorgcc with which I call icecc. But I had also have defined a link on g++ in my home bin directory.
So it seems, that you have also a problem with PATH. Try doing this command for helping you to find path problem:

> strace -f -e execve icecc g++ a.cpp -c

Answer (score 0):

I had setup ccache to call icecc (via config setting in ~/.config/ccache/ccache.conf: prefix_command=icecc), which meant I didn't need to put /usr/lib/icecc/bin into my PATH environment variable.